# Highlight a single point in a boxplot in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot, boxplot

I have a boxplot in Plotly. I would like to overlay a single point on some of the boxes. I thought I could do this by adding a scatter trace to the `fig`, but when I look into the data of the figure I can't see anything specifying the y coordinate of the boxes so I'm not sure how to overlay the point. How can I add a single point to some boxes in a boxplot?

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

N = 10

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Box(
    x=2.5 * np.sin(np.pi * i/N) + i/N + (1.5 + 0.5 * np.cos(np.pi*i/N)) * np.random.rand(10),
    ) for i in range(int(N))])

fig.update_layout(height=600)
fig
```

Result:
[image]

Ideal Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify y values for multiple boxplots, plotly assigns them y values of `"trace 0",..."trace 9"` in its coordinate system (even though you won't be able to see them when you look at the `fig` object, as you noticed).

So you can calculate the mean (or whatever statistic is intended to be shown by the red scatter points), and pass the arguments `x = [{mean1}, ... {mean9}]` and `y=["trace 0", ... "trace 9"]` to `go.Scatter` and they will appear on the figure.

For example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

N = 10

# for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42) 

boxplot_data = []
scatter_mean = []
for i in range(int(N)):
    data_array = 2.5 * np.sin(np.pi * i/N) + i/N + (1.5 + 0.5 * np.cos(np.pi*i/N)) * np.random.rand(10)
    boxplot_data += [go.Box(x=data_array)]
    scatter_mean += [np.mean(data_array)]


fig = go.Figure(data=boxplot_data)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=scatter_mean,
    y=[f"trace {i}" for i in range(len(boxplot_data))],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(color="red"),
    showlegend=False
))

fig.update_layout(height=600)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed that's what I am looking for. Well done